# How to Fix "Error: Please specify a valid Spreadsheet URL."

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm using a stock Google Apps Script for Link Checker (https://developers.google.com/google-ads/scripts/docs/solutions/link-checker#source-code). I've copied the template spreadsheet to reference but I keep getting response "Error: Please specify a valid Spreadsheet URL."

The part of the code that seems to be the issue is the 3rd row below:

```
function validateAndGetSpreadsheet(spreadsheeturl) {
  if (spreadsheeturl == 'YOUR_SPREADSHEET_URL') {
    throw new Error('Please specify a valid Spreadsheet URL. You can find' +
        ' a link to a template in the associated guide for this script.');
```

I've input my URL to replace the 'YOUR_SPREADSHEET_URL' but am not sure what I'm supposed to input into the

```
'Please specify a valid Spreadsheet URL. You can find' +
        ' a link to a template in the associated guide for this script.'
```

I tried putting the my spreadsheet URL in there, and also I tried leaving it out, but neither works. I am a complete Google Scripts novice so any help would be gratefully received!

Answer (score 0):

You need to have changed the URL parameter on here:

```
var CONFIG = {
  SPREADSHEET_URL: 'YOUR_SPREADSHEET_URL',
```